# How can I save data inside a TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsuserdefaults

In my app I have a label that, when user tap the view o shake the iPhone, it will change the quote in random. If the user double tap the same view, it should save the quote inside a TableView.
At the beginning, I thought I could use CoreData, but he didn't work. Now I'm using UserDefaults, And now if I double tap the view, the quote is saved, but only one at time. What I want that to do is that he create a list of all the quotes that a the user double tapped on.

Here's the code inside the doubleTap Object:

```
let savedQuotes = UserDefaults.standard.setValue(quoteLabel.text!, forKey: "saveQuotes")

    if let printSavedQuotes = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "saveQuotes"){

        print(printSavedQuotes)

    }
```

And here's the code that I used inside for the TableVIew:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    _ = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "saveQuotes")

    return 15
    
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuoteCell", for: indexPath)
    
    if let printSavedQuotes = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "saveQuotes"){
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(printSavedQuotes)"
        
    }
```

Here's an image of the problem.

[image: Here's an image of the problem]

Comment: You don't save data in a tableView. You **display** data using it. Also, why do you have a userdefaults call inside `heightForRowAt` that you are not even using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as like below approach..

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let savedQuotes = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saveQuotes") as? [String] ?? [String]()

    return saveQuotes.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuoteCell", for: indexPath)

    let saveQuotes = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saveQuotes") as? [String] ?? [String]()

    cell.textLabel?.text = saveQuotes[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func saveQuote(){

    var saveQuotes = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "saveQuotes") as? [String] ?? [String]()

    saveQuotes.append(quoteLabel.text!)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(saveQuotes, forKey: "saveQuotes")

    print(saveQuotes)
}
```

This is just an example, recommended approach is use sqlite or core-data to store persistent data instead of UserDefaults.

Comment: Don't suggest `value(forKey` to retrieve data from `UserDefaults`. In this case there is `array(forKey` and in the other *object* cases use `object(forKey`. And it's discouraged anyway from using `UserDefaults` as data source.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. Now the only problem is how to delate the saved quotes, because now it delate all the quotes that I saved

Answer (score 2):

Please learn about `Collections` in Swift. What your'e looking for is an `Array` type. A type that represents a collection of elements stored in a specific order.

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Now when you learn how to save things into the array, you can connect this array to your `tableView`.

The very basic setup is:

`var quotes: [String] = ["quote1", "quote2", "quote3"]`

In `numberOfRowsInSection` you return `quotes.count`

and in `cellForRow` your `cell.textLabel.text == quotes[indexPath.row]`